# After adding a custom button, how to update the cart total onclick?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Imagine that i have added a custom button on cart page table. Below every product one button (cart listed in products table).

Onclick the button need to update the cart total on ajax. I tried with below function.

Added this hook '`wp_footer`'. You can see that on `input.qty(change keyup mouseup)` it works fine. But on click `a.btn.plus` is not working.

`console.log(jQuery('input.qty').val());` is printing qty but trigger function is not working.

If I am adding trigger function outside of onclick it is working ?

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a.btn.plus', function () {
    if (timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(timeout); 

    if (jQuery('input.qty').val() == '') return;

    timeout = setTimeout(function () {

        //jQuery('[name="update_cart"]').trigger('click');

        console.log(jQuery('input.qty').val());

        jQuery('button.primary.mt-0.pull-left.small').trigger('click');

    }, 1000);

});

jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change keyup mouseup', 'input.qty', function () {

    if (timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(timeout); 

    if (jQuery(this).val() == '') return; 

    timeout = setTimeout(function () {

        jQuery('[name="update_cart"]').trigger('click');

    }, 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   `<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeout;
    jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('click', 'a.btn.plus', function () {
       if (timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
       jQuery(jQuery('body').find('[name="update_cart"]')).prop('disabled',false);
       jQuery(jQuery('body').find('[name="update_cart"]')).trigger('click');
       }, 1000);
    });
    </script>`
```

Comment: instead of finding name="update_cart" first select body then find the  name working......